# Having problems while generating barcode in rails using BARBY gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using:

- ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.5
- ruby gems 1.3.6
- Windows 7 Home Basic 64-bit
- barby 0.5.0

I'm having problems to generate barcodes for my app. I installed barby 0.5.0 and I was hoping that it would solve my problems. But everytime it generates a file, it seems that it's broken or damaged. It can't be opened. I wonder what I'm doing wrong here.

As for the stack trace, there's really no error.

Here's my code:

```
barcodevalue = "00000000000"
full_path = "barcode#{barcode_value}.png"
barcode = Barby::Code39.new(barcode_value)
File.open(full_path, 'w') { |f| f.write barcode.to_png(:margin => 3, :xdim => 2,     :height => 55) }
render :text => "#{barcode_value}.png has been generated."
```

Comment: And what is the generated file like?

Comment: i am also having the same problem?? did u found any answer on this??

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link for answer.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-barby/8Vgh-CLNfuI